# How to get file bytes with Dropbox Chooser for Android

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using [Dropbox chooser for Android](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android).

```
mDropboxChooser.forResultType(DbxChooser.ResultType.FILE_CONTENT)
                    .launch(SendActivity.this,
                            DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and in onActivityResult I get the url

```
DbxChooser.Result result = new DbxChooser.Result(data);
            Uri u = result.getLink();
```

but I am not sure how can I get file bytes using this Uri.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use that `Uri` to open an input stream connection, that is from where you'll get the bytes, presumably making a HttpUriRequest. But I'm not sure, just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Andy Res's answer as an answer, because he's right. :-)

> I think you are supposed to use that Uri to open an input stream
>   connection, that is from where you'll get the bytes, presumably making
>   a HttpUriRequest.

**EDIT**

Also note that you should get a "direct" link, not a "preview" link if you want to download the file contents.

Comment: This is the urlI get file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/cache/tmp/ch/es_appicon_128.png and if I try to create a File from this File file = new File(url.toString()); I get the size zero file and this exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/cache/tmp/ch/es_appicon_128.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , but when I go to my files there is the file in this folder. I am not sure about HttpUrl request for files with local path, but I am new to this, so maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Ok, I got it. This 'file:///' was making a problem. And if I use DIRECT LINK I get the https like to the file, so HttpRequest makes sense, but if I use CONTENT I get file bytes using file I create as I described in the last comment.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were using `FILE_CONTENT`. You *should* be able to just read that file. But I think you want `newFile(url.getPath())`, not `newFile(url.toString())`.

Comment: You are right. I was removing some parts manually, but getPath() gets files path directly.